# QImage::transformed SEGFAULT

Tags: c++, qt

I have app that gets images from photo cameras for future processing. Initialy I get images as QByteArray buffer and then process them as follows:

```
QImage image;
QMatrix rm;
rm.rotate(90);//I need vertical aligned picture
image.loadFromData(buf_);//buf_ is raw data QByteArray
if(image.isNull())
{
    emit error();
    return;
}
QImage trans_image = image.transformed(rm);
trans_image.save(path_, "JPG", 100);
```

Regulary I get crash on prelast string.

Stack looks like that:

```
1   qt_memrotate270_tiled_unpacked<unsigned int>                                                                                      qmemrotate.cpp           212  0x1b2ec6c  
2   qt_memrotate270_template<unsigned int>                                                                                            qmemrotate.cpp           275  0x1b2ec6c  
3   qt_memrotate270                                                                                                                   qmemrotate.cpp           315  0x1b2ec6c  
4   qt_memrotate270_32                                                                                                                qmemrotate.cpp           377  0x1b2ecd3  
5   rotated90                                                                                                                         qimage.cpp               4520 0x1a07c3f  
6   QImage::transformed                                                                                                               qimage.cpp               4627 0x1a0a502  
7   QImage::transformed                                                                                                               qimage.cpp               2792 0x1a0b1ce  
8   Camera::processImage                                                                                                              camera.cpp               293  0x438bea   
...
```

Sometimes it takes 5-6 pictures, sometimes 50-60.

Image variable looks pretty ok in debugger, not Invalid or anything like that. What can be reason for such crash and how can I deal with it (at least catch an error to avoid segfault)?

Qt 5.10.0

Comment: Did you try find relation between size of the bytearray buffer `buf_` and crashes .. I don't see you are checking the buffer size in your code, to make sure images are buffered.

Comment: There is check for empty buffer, it was just above copyed code, so I missed it during copypaste, and even so if buffer is corrupt or empty image should be null and it will be checked. Also when I test cameras are shooting nearly similar images, they don't move, light don't change and there is nearly no movement in front of them, so images are of similar size.

Comment: my suggestion is to lock the format instead of letting the loader "Guess" .. `image.loadFromData(buf_,QImage::Format_RGB32);`

Comment: QImage::loadFromData won't take color format, it requires const char* format like "JPEG" or "PNG" and nope, it won't fix the problem.

Comment: It really shouldn't affect the result, but... what is the value returned by `image.loadFromData(buf_)`?

Comment: @CrazySage : You say that there is a check for empty buffer. But a null byte array might not be an empty byte array. Is it possible that it could be causing you problems ?

Comment: I check by using isNull(). And at least start of QByteArray looks like proper jpeg header with exif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, that hi-res camera images are too big to be handled by 32-bit library, migrating to 64-bit Qt solved this problem.